# VB.NET - Hiding Form on Load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So theres a few questions on this but they all give the same answer `Me.Hide()` which "works" if you count that when it loads, It will SHOW but then will hide seconds after which makes a weird Shadow-y-Laggy Effect.

Example:
[image: 1]
(The small Window that shows and almost instantly hides is the window im trying to NEVER show)

Is there a way to actually hide the WHOLE form upon load? I know of the whole VisibilityCore method but with that I cant find a way to show it again at a later point.

So is there a way to hide it so it NEVER shows unless I tell it to Show?

Currently im using "Hide() combined with Form.Show Method".

Comment: Can't you just set the Visible property to false?

Comment: @DigitalBrain By the looks of things it doesn't do anything. I tried it just now again and still nothing has changed. (I executed it before Hide() on Form.Load)

Comment: You can create the form instance and then only show it when you want.  I assume that is the "main form" in which case, it is the VB App Framework loading and showing it for you.

Comment: I use the `Shown` event on Windows 7. I never see it flicker like this. What happens if you call `Form.Visible = False` right after the `Form.Show()` call?

Comment: @VisualVincent I dont use Show() I set it to load on Application Open using the Application Settings in Application Properties.

Comment: Oh... Well, blame Windows 10 for not being fast enough. ;p

Comment: Just to mention the Form is secondary to the main form I called it "UpdateCheck" instead of "Form2" and I set it to load "UpdateCheck" instead of "Form1" using Application Settings so basically, I open the exe and it Loads "UpdateCheck" then later on it will do some code and eventually "Form1.Show()" (Form1 is the main application which is what brings the "PRAGMA 1.1" green thing to show)

Comment: @VisualVincent Do you have skype? Could you test run the app to see if it happens to you? If so add me: toolnet.work

Comment: I don't add random people. Also, I don't have time at the moment and I am writing this off my phone :). Though my answer should do it for you.

Comment: If you have code related to Update which doesnt perform user interaction, dont put it in a form.  You can put the code in a class, run it, then show the real form when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the form's `Opacity` property to `0` (through the Property Window) you shouldn't have this problem.

When you want to show the form (if it's going to be shown at all) just set the opacity back to `1.0`.

Comment: @ShinyMK : \*Ahem\* mark it as the answer, please \*ahem\* :)

Comment: IMHO this is a hack answer - use Sub Main() instead.  That's what it's there for.

Comment: @MrGadget : It's only a hack depending on what it's used for. If it's used to hide an actual form (for some reason) to then show it later it is not a hacky way :).

Answer (score 2):

Opacity is still a hack.  The correct way is to not show it at all, versus making it invisible. To do this, don't make it the "Startup Object" at all.

On the Application tab of the Project Properties screen, there is a Startup Object setting.  Create a Module with a Sub Main() and make that the entry point of your app by selecting it as the Startup Object instead of that little form that apparently doesn't do anything visual.

Maybe you have some initialization code in that starting form...move that to Sub Main.

Answer (score 0):

you can minimize the form upon application launch.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form fm = new Form1();
        fm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        Application.Run(fm);

    }
```